# How to trigger asp code behind from the button in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, linq

Can anyone teach me how to trigger the asp code behind after i click on the button at appear at the jquery popup dialog? I want my data to send to server side

Here is my form :

```
<div id="dialog" hidden>

 fullname:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></br>
 password:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></br>
 email:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></br>

<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" hidden/>

</div>
```

My jquery dialog which will pop up my form:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >

jQuery(document).ready(function () {


    $('#<%=open.ClientID%>').click(function () {

        $('#dialog').dialog({ modal: true,
            height: 500,
            width: 600,
            resizable: false,
            show: 'fold',
            hide: 'fold',
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here is my asp code behind. I'm using linq to show the data in the gridview:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showData();
    }


     protected void showData()
     {
         using(AutoBetDataContext db = new AutoBetDataContext())
         {
             var query = from u in db.UserDetails
                         select u;

             GridView.DataSource= query;
             GridView.DataBind();
         }
     }

     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         using (AutoBetDataContext db = new AutoBetDataContext())
         {
             UserDetail user = new UserDetail();
             user.Fullname = TextBox1.Text;
             user.Password = TextBox2.Text;
             user.EmailAddress = TextBox3.Text;
             db.UserDetails.InsertOnSubmit(user);
             db.SubmitChanges();
             showData();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little further please. what button is `open`? Is `open`'s only purpose to pop up the dialogue? In the dialogue (which was hidden), you have `Button_1` - what happens when you click it? I'm guessing the page refreshes but your dialogue is hidden again? If this is the case, are you form element populated as expected?

Comment: The "open" is the button only to trigger the popup when onclicked. The whole div is hidden included the textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, and the submit button(which i want to use this button to trigger the code behind). The div(dialog) cannot be seen until i click the "open" button, it will popup.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be returning false at the end when dialog is clicked..

```
 });
 return false;
```

This will  prevent the postback from occurring..

Try **return true** here..

If that does not help you have to explicitly call the **__doPostback()**

Comment: if i remove the return false, my dialog will not come up. The return false is use to prevent the dialog from auto close.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your problem is with the `command` button - It would appear more to do with the post back, the page is refresh and your dialogue box has no means to be displayed.

You click `open` and display the dialogue, then `return false` to prevent a postback.

Then in the dialogue, you enter the details and click the button with ID `Submit` - This triggers a postback, which fires the event `Button1_Click`.

To stop the form from being populated with the new data, personally I would alter the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { // Only do this if the page is a fresh request.
        showData();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the page will load, the new details will be loaded.

However, as the page is now posted back, jQuery knows nothing of this, and therefore the dialogue is hidden (as per a normal page load).

You could always have a hidden field:

```
<asp:hidden id="hdnOpenDialogue" runat="server" value="false" />
```

Then in the `Button1_Click` run `hdnOpenDialogue.value = "true";`

Then use the following jQuery:

```
$('[id$="hdnOpenDialogue"]').each(function(idx) {
    if($(this).attr("value") == "true") {
                $('#dialog').dialog({ modal: true, height: 500,
                        width: 600, resizable: false,
                        how: 'fold', hide: 'fold',
                  }
               });       
    };
});
```

Then this will open your dialogue if the hidden field is set to "true"

This is more a theory into how to keep your dialogue open after postback, not a copy this verbatim, as I've just coded it off the top of my head!